# Partitioning an array to maximal number of groups

Tags: algorithm, recursive-backtracking

There is only one rule to follow: each group's sum should be greater or equal to the group on right side of it.

My guess is to build a tree with all the options for partitioning exist and then recursive backtracking.

For example, the array 14 13 2 11

The result : 3.  3 groups ({14}, {13}, {2, 11})

Do you think my guess is true? if not do you have other solution to the problem?

Comment: If all elements must be positive, I guess greedy approach will work here, though I might be missing something

Comment: tried greedy approach from both sides and found input that ruled out the greedy approach

Comment: Can you please show me counter example for greedy from right side? As I said, I might be missing something, and the counter example will show me what. (If negatives are allowed, I am convinced it's not going to work)

Comment: I think 10,10,1,2,1,2 is a counterexample (greedy does 10,10,1|2,1|2 I guess since it gets stuck trying to make the last group after grabbing 10,1; optimal is 10|10|1,2,1|2).

Comment: Certainly there's an O(n^2)-time DP, and probably a faster one, so backtracking is not the best approach.

Comment: you're right David there is a solution that  is a better than O(n^2*sqrt(n)) i have been told

Comment: Are the array entries all nonnegative?

Comment: yes all numbers from 1 to 5n^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `O(n^2)`-time algorithm, where `n` is the length of the array. I retract my comment that there's "probably" a faster one.

There's a simpler `O(n^4)`-time algorithm that illustrates the main idea of the dynamic program. We prepare a table of entries `T(i, j)` where the `i, j` entry contains the maximum number of groups into which the array elements indexed `[0, j)` can be grouped suitably in such a way that the last group has indexes `[i, j)`.

We have a recurrence

```
T(0, j) = 1 for all j
T(i, j) =          max          T(h, i) + 1,
          h : S(h, i) ≥ S(i, j)
```

where `S(i, j)` is the sum of array elements indexed `[i, j)`, and an empty max is taken to be minus infinity. The answer is

```
max T(i, n).
 i
```

We get to `O(n^4)` because for `O(n^2)` table entries, we compute a maximum over `O(n)` sums, each of `O(n)` items.

We make two optimizations. The first is easy: update the sum `S(h, i)` incrementally as we vary `h`. This drops the cost to `O(n^3)`. We can do the same for `S(i, j)`, but to no effect yet assuming that we sensibly hoisted it out of the max loop.

The second depends on nonnegative entries. For particular `i, j`, the set of valid `h` is an interval like `[0, k)`, possibly empty. For `i` fixed and `j` decreasing, the sum `S(i, j)` is nonincreasing, hence the interval does not shrink. This means that we can update the max incrementally as well, yielding an `O(n^2)`-time algorithm.

Comment: Two questions: If n=4 the size of the table is 5x5 ? And what do you mean by empty max?